# Count most frequent word in row by R

Tags: r, word-frequency

There is a table shown below

```
   Name     Mon    Tue     Wed    Thu     Fri    Sat    Sun

1 John     Apple  Orange  Apple  Banana  Apple  Apple  Orange
2 Ricky    Banana Apple   Banana Banana  Banana Banana Apple
3 Alex     Apple  Orange  Orange Apple   Apple  Orange Orange
4 Robbin   Apple  Apple   Apple  Apple   Apple  Banana Banana
5 Sunny    Banana Banana  Apple  Apple   Apple  Banana Banana
```

So , I want to count the most frequent Fruit for each person and add those value in new column.

For example.

```
   Name     Mon    Tue     Wed    Thu     Fri    Sat    Sun      Max_Acc  Count

1 John     Apple  Orange  Apple  Banana  Apple  Apple  Orange     Apple       4
2 Ricky    Banana Apple   Banana Banana  Banana Banana Apple      Banana      5
3 Alex     Apple  Orange  Orange Apple   Apple  Orange Orange     Orange      4
4 Robbin   Apple  Apple   Apple  Apple   Apple  Banana Banana     Apple       5
5 Sunny    Banana Banana  Apple  Apple   Apple  Banana Banana     Banana      4
```

I am facing problem in finding rows. I can find Frequency in column by using `table()` function.

```
>table(df$Mon)

 Apple  Banana
  3      2
```

But here i want name of most frequent fruit in new column.

Comment: Please give a `dput` of your data. It could be that df[1, ] solves your problem.

Comment: @Christoph But there is 2k Rows so Its going to tough for run this to 1 to 2k times.

Comment: I only need a sample, e.g. row 1-10 ;-)

Comment: Try with `df1$Count <- apply(df1[-1], 1,  function(x) max(table(x)))` or using `data.table` i..e `setDT(df1)[, Count := max(table(unlist(.SD))), Name]`

Comment: @akrun its only give me max count...But i also want the name which fruit having max count .

Comment: @akrun  how can i get name of fruit which is most frequent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the "Count" and "Names" corresponding to the `max` "Count", we loop through the rows of the dataset (using `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`), use `table` to get the frequency, extract the maximum value from it and the `names` corresponding to the maximum value, `rbind` it and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
cbind(df1, do.call(rbind, apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) {
              x1 <- table(x)
             data.frame(Count = max(x1), Names=names(x1)[which.max(x1)])})))

#    Name    Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat    Sun Count  Names
#1   John  Apple Orange  Apple Banana  Apple  Apple Orange     4  Apple
#2  Ricky Banana  Apple Banana Banana Banana Banana  Apple     5 Banana
#3   Alex  Apple Orange Orange  Apple  Apple Orange Orange     4 Orange
#4 Robbin  Apple  Apple  Apple  Apple  Apple Banana Banana     5  Apple
#5  Sunny Banana Banana  Apple  Apple  Apple Banana Banana     4 Banana
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("Names", "Count") := {tbl <- table(unlist(.SD))
                    .(names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)], max(tbl))}, by = Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to loop over all unique fruits as follows

```
fruits_unique <- unique(unlist(dat[-1]))
occurence <- sapply(fruits_unique, function(x) rowSums(dat[,-1] == x)) 
# Using this data to create the resulting columns
ind <- apply(occurence,1,which.max)
dat$Names <- fruits_unique[ind]
dat$count <- occurence[cbind(seq_along(ind), ind)]
```

Result:

```
    Name    Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat    Sun  Names Count
1   John  Apple Orange  Apple Banana  Apple  Apple Orange  Apple     4
2  Ricky Banana  Apple Banana Banana Banana Banana  Apple Banana     5
3   Alex  Apple Orange Orange  Apple  Apple Orange Orange Orange     4
4 Robbin  Apple  Apple  Apple  Apple  Apple Banana Banana  Apple     5
5  Sunny Banana Banana  Apple  Apple  Apple Banana Banana Banana     4
```